# How to implement PIVOT in SQL?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table **Transaction_Info**, which comprises of following columns:
**Customer_Id**,
**Total_sales**,
**Transaction_Date**

I want to make SQL Pivot on the **Year of Trasanction_Date** for **Total_Sales**.

I have written the following SQL query:

```
DECLARE   @SQLQuery AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE   @PivotColumns AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @PivotColumns = STUFF( (SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ QUOTENAME(CAST(YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) AS VARCHAR(255)))
                       FROM TRANSACTION_INFO
                       FOR XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 1, ''
                    )

SET @SQLQuery = 
N'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, '+ @PivotColumns + '
FROM TRANSACTION_INFO
PIVOT(SUM(TOTAL_AMT) FOR YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) IN (' +@PivotColumns+')) AS P'
```

The following is resulting in the expected output.

```
SELECT @PivotColumns

--OUTPUT

[2013], [2011], [2012], [2014]


SELECT @SQLQuery

-- OUTPUT

SELECT CUSTOMER_ID,  [2013], [2011], [2012], [2014]FROM TRANSACTION_INFOPIVOT(SUM(TOTAL_AMT) FOR YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) IN ( [2013], [2011], [2012], [2014])) AS P
```

But the following is returning an error **Incorrect syntax near '('**

```
EXEC sp_executesql @SQLQuery
```

I am unable to figure out the error. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Comment: So rather than just telling us that `select @SQLQuery` had the "expected output", could you *share* that output with us as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get to apply *arbitrary* expressions where SQL expects a column name. Use a subquery to first extract the year value and pivot on that:

```
N'SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, '+ @PivotColumns + '
FROM (SELECT
         CUSTOMER_ID,
         TOTAL_AMT,
         YEAR(TRANSACTION_DATE) as TRANSACTION_YEAR
      FROM TRANSACTION_INFO) TI
PIVOT(SUM(TOTAL_AMT) FOR TRANSACTION_YEAR IN (' +@PivotColumns+')) AS P'
```

Note the [Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017#syntax)<sup>1</sup>:

```
PIVOT  
(  
    <aggregation function>(<column being aggregated>)  
FOR   
[<column that contains the values that will become column headers>]   
    IN ( [first pivoted column], [second pivoted column],  
    ... [last pivoted column])  
) AS <alias for the pivot table>
```

All of these placeholders asking for a `column` mean exactly that. You can't use expressions here. Note this also, for example, means that you cannot perform any kind of complex calculation within the aggregate.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note however that there is a documentation bug here. `<column that contains the values that will become column headers>` isn't optional.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want a group by

```
SELECT customer_id, year(transaction_date) as year, sum(total_sales) as total
FROM transaction_info
GROUP BY customer_id, year(transaction_date)
```

Comment: No, i wan't the total sales for individual customers for all the years listed in the dataset.

Comment: I see... you want a column for every year?

Answer (score -1):

in order to PIVOT - you need to use a square brackets in a "@PivotColumns" list..
I feel I need to provide a simple example, formatting a list - is up to you.
A globally virtual table used in example as a parameter cannot be used in a "text":

```
begin try
    drop table #pvt
end try
begin catch
end catch

create table #pvt(VendorID int, Emp1 int, Emp2 int,
    Emp3 int, Emp4 int, Emp5 int)

INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (1,4,3,5,4,4)
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (2,4,1,5,5,5)
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (3,4,3,5,4,4)
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (4,4,2,5,5,4)
INSERT INTO #pvt VALUES (5,5,1,5,5,5)

select * from #pvt 
------------------------------------
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM #pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt
----------------------------------------
select pv.* 
from(
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM #pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt
) t
pivot (sum(Orders) for Employee in([Emp1],[Emp2],[Emp3],[Emp4],[Emp5])) pv

declare @sql varchar(max)
set @sql='select pv.* 
from(
--Unpivot the table.
SELECT VendorID, Employee, Orders
FROM 
   (SELECT VendorID, Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5
   FROM #pvt) p
UNPIVOT
   (Orders FOR Employee IN 
      (Emp1, Emp2, Emp3, Emp4, Emp5)
)AS unpvt
) t
pivot (sum(Orders) for Employee in([Emp1],[Emp2],[Emp3],[Emp4],[Emp5])) pv'
exec(@sql)
```

Comment: You don't *have* to use square brackets, but if they need to, they've already covered this since they're using `QUOTENAME` to wrap the values that are to become columns.

Comment: coping an example using different data is not useful -- the question is specific not generic -- a generic answer is pointless.